# Sync databases from different servers

Tags: sql-server, data-synchronization

I have the following setup:

One SQL Server on one side, another on the other. The two can't connect, so no possibility to a linked server. It is possible to place the MDFs and LDFs in a shared folder. One of the two SQL Servers is always online, the other one isn't.

On both sides I have an application which uses the same data. I only use the application on one side because I can't share the database and they are not synchronized.

What is a possible way to use the application on both sides (not at the same time) without restoring backups to have up-to-date data. Synchronizing would be awesome but is it possible?

Comment: Can you clarify your question to specify what "side" means? Both sides of what? Use the [edit] button to make that clear please.

Answer (score 2):

If you can control that only one SQL Server is started at one point in time, then I could imagine that having the database file on an UNC share could be an option. It is supported, as of SMB 3.0 (Windows Server 2012).

You create the database on one of the SQL Servers using an UNC path for the database files.

Then I suppose on the other machine, you would attach the database (CREATE DATABASE FOR ATTACH) specifying the file names. This part I didn't test, but I don't see a reason why it wouldn't work.

Your challenge would be to make sure that the two SQL Servers are never started at the same time. I have my doubts of ending up with something robust regarding this aspect, to be honest.

Answer (score -2):

Sounds like you need some sort of replication - most likely MERGE replication but there is not enough information to give you a definitive answer.

There's an introduction to Merge replication here giving a good overview of the use cases :-

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/merge/merge-replication?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: From the OP: "*The two can't connect, so no possibility [of] a linked server.*" - if the servers can't communicate with each other, merge replication is off the table.

Comment: remote distributor then ?